# Additional Drivers - What does this error means?

Tags: intel-graphics

[image]

Should I use manually installed one?

Comment: Have you tried to install drivers by yourself or was it like that since the installation ?

Comment: I installed and updated. Nothing added manually.

Comment: The "manually installed driver" could be a bad implementation from the Ubuntu distribution. You should use the open source option in most cases except for Nvidia.

Comment: Thanks @JerareYoshi